# Ubuntu 18.04 not seeing hyperthreading

Tags: kernel, bios

Hyperthreading is definitely Enabled in BIOS.

But htop is showing only 18 processors, and so lscpu showing only 1 thread per CPU. (it is a i9 with 18 physical cores).

How can I enable ubuntu to detect and use hyperthreading?